# Salesforce1 - Reset history with force:navigateToComponent

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, salesforce1-app, mobile, ios

I am currently working on an app created with lightning components. 
My app includes five different components, which I call with `force:navigateToComponent` from each other. 
I added a lightning tab including the first component to the mobile navigation bar.

So the general navigation between the components looks like this:
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 1 -> 2 ->3 ...

For mobile devices Salesforce includes a navigation header:
[image: Salesforce iOS Header]

On iOS-devices using Salesforce1 the navigation changes like this when I navigate to the next component:

[image: Navigation after navigate to component]

Unfortunately the icon for toggling the sidebar ([image: toggle nav]) is disappearing as soon as you leave the first screen. So in order to leave the app the user is forced to press the back-button ([image: back button]) till the icon to toggle the sidebar ([image: toggle nav]) is appearing again. When the user iterates multiple times through the app this is really frustrating.

Is there any solution how to show the toggle-icon permanently like this? (When using device toolbar of developer tools in chrome it actually looks like this)
[image: Wish]

Or to at least show the toggle-icon ([image: toggle nav]) on the first component so the user can exit the app?

Is it somehow possible to toggle the sidebar on button click?

Answer (score 0):

My scenario is a bit alike. Although I used force:navigateToComponent specifically because it makes standard "back" arrow show itself in sf1 app. So my guess is you should use a different approach to navigation - try using navigateToUrl or even navigation without using events - just showing and hiding markup dynamically.
As far as I know, there's no way to apply any settings to header in sf1 directly in LEX.

Comment: This post seems like a legitimate attempt to answer the question. Not sure why it's getting reviewed as if that's not the case.